# node.js socket.io on page refresh try keep connection?

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io, reload, reconnect

Socket.io client or websocket client is a javascript object that gets destroyed and 
recreated when the page reloads, thus causing the disconnection and the reconnection. I dont know how can that affect node.js server performance, if this happens for every client on every page refresh?

How bad/good practise is creating new socket connection on every page refresh? I think that this is nessesary in complex web sites with many different pages on different routes(php in background), if i want use socket.io for realtime support. Or? Any alternative solution?

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you must work across multiple page loads, you don't have a choice.  As you have discovered, you must re-connect for each page.

Comment: Are there any other effective technology for doing that?

Comment: For doing what, specifically?

Comment: For realtime support, with work across multiple page loads.

Comment: All you need to do is reconnect when the page loads.  You're doing that anyway to connect in the first place, right?

Comment: Yes of course, but question is up.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  When you go to a new page, every bit of it is torn down client-side.  Nothing can persist from page-to-page.  Everything must be re-created on page load.  Just keep a session ID in a cookie so you can reload your support chat box from where you left off on the next page load.

Comment: It won't affect the performance since Node.js keeps tracks of connected sockets. Once a socket dies, it flushes it out of its memory.